# Remove CodeMap from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-map

Is there any way to remove the CodeMap menus from the contextual menu on Visual Studio 2015?

I use a lot the "Find references" feature, and since on VS2015 they changed it's position and added the awful functionality of references on codemap on it's old place I really get mad each time I click on it instead of on find references.

I would be more than happy if I can fully remove all the CodeMap functionalities from VS2015 not just the menus.

Comment: I agree, VS2015 seems to crash on this when I drag  CodeMap to my second screen.  Nice shiny things are for nice shiny clueless people, give us tools that can burn holes through those damn bugs...

Comment: Hi @Schwarzie2478 - does this bug still repro on VS 2015 Update 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to remove Code Map from Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition.

The old "Find All References" is still on the context menu. You can also view all the references from the CodeLens references indicator that appears over each method and each class. Both of these options have key accelerators - shift+F12 and ALT+2 respectively.

Comment: More than not being useful the problem is it messed up very old customs, I can see in some cases it would be very useful, but changing my mind on how I used VS for 13 years is just a pain...

Comment: The team is looking at reorganizing the Code Map contextual commands in the next version of Visual Studio (but take this with a grain of salt as I am not in charge of the product backlog).

Comment: Woah! that's a ray of light on my day!! Thanks for the info!